# Overlap of two date ranges in minutes in SQL

Tags: postgresql, date, range, overlap

Is there an easy way to get the overlap in minutes of two date ranges in SQL? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function will handle any input of 4 timestamps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_overlap(start1 timestamp, end1 timestamp, start2 timestamp, end2 timestamp) RETURNS int STRICT AS '

  -- STRICT returns NULL if any input is NULL

  BEGIN

    -- for valid ranges, end1 must be after (or equal to) start1, end2 must be after (or equal to) start2
    -- for valid overlap, either end1 is after (or equal to) start2 or end2 is after (or equal to) start1

    IF end1 < start1 OR end2 < start2 OR start1 < start2 AND end1 < start2 OR start2 < start1 AND end2 < start1 THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
      IF start1 > start2 THEN
        IF end1 < end2 THEN
          RETURN EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM end1 - start1) :: int/60;
        ELSE
          RETURN EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM end2 - start1) :: int/60;
        END IF;
      ELSE
        IF end2 < end1 THEN
          RETURN EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM end2 - start2) :: int/60;
        ELSE
          RETURN EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM end1 - start2) :: int/60;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;    
  END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Usage:

```
SELECT date_overlap(timestamp1, timestamp2, timestamp3, timestamp4) FROM myTable
```

Returns: # mins as int

Comment: Thanks good solution, if you want days you can change int/60 and put int/60/60/24

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each date range consists of two date fields; first range: date1, date2, second range: date3, date4 and the first range ends after the second one begins.

```
SELECT (date3 - date2) * interval '1 minute' FROM myTable
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: You probably meant (date2 - date3). But what if [date1, date2] is completely inside [date3, date4]?

Comment: yup... (date2 - date3) - thanx.  Also, good point about the one range being completely inside the other... only way is with a function... I'll post it separately.

Answer (score 0):

**

```
Declare @Table Table  
(  
    RowId Int Identity(1, 1) Not Null, 
      Id NChar(3) Not Null, 
      StartDate DATETIME Not Null, 
      EndDate DATETIME Not Null 
);  

Insert Into @Table (Id, StartDate, EndDate)  
Select 'id1', '20131210 10:10', '20131220 10:10' Union All  
Select 'id1', '20131211', '20131215' Union All  
Select 'id1', '20131201', '20131205' Union All  
Select 'id1', '20131206', '20131208' Union All  
Select 'id1', '20131225 10:10', '20131225 10:11'
Select *  
From @Table;  


With Overlaps (OverlapRowId, BaseRowId, OStart, OEnd, BStart, BEnd)  
As  
(  
        Select Overlap.RowId, Base.RowId, Overlap.StartDate, Overlap.EndDate, Base.StartDate, Base.EndDate 
        From @Table As Base  
        Inner Join @Table As Overlap On Overlap.Id = Base.Id  
        Where (((Overlap.StartDate > Base.StartDate) And (Overlap.StartDate < Base.EndDate))
          Or ((Overlap.StartDate = Base.StartDate) And (Overlap.EndDate > Base.EndDate))) 
          And (Base.RowId != Overlap.RowId) 
) 
-- Remove records that were found to cause overlap issues.  
Delete T  
From @Table As T  
Inner Join  
(  
        Select O.OverlapRowId   
        From Overlaps As O 
        Left Join Overlaps As Fp On Fp.OverlapRowId = O.BaseRowId  
        Where (Fp.OverlapRowId Is Null) 
) As SubQuery On SubQuery.OverlapRowId = T.RowId;  

-- Select the valid options.  
Select RowId, Id, StartDate, EndDate  
From @Table where StartDate<EndDate;  
Go
```

**